# Thru-hiking and crossing cold water

Tags: trekking, water

Several thru-hike trails have water-sections. For example, [the American discovery trail](https://discoverytrail.org/the-trail/) requires crossing the Chesapeake Bay under the bay bridge (no pedestrians allowed). This is a 6km stretch of water that drops to 5C in winter. There is no? public transport across the bridge. **Be wary of water currents in any body of water.**

But how would *self-supported* group of thru-hikers cross it? **A self-supported thru-hike is extremally difficult. Do not attempt without extensive training, preparation and emergency rescue measures.**. That being said, for a self-supported trip you will have to carry all your non-disposable equipment for the entire duration so weight restrictions are severe.

1. Inflatable kayak/canoe. Weights far less than any rigid hulled boat.
2. In-situ construction: Make a single-use canoe out of reeds and other available materials.  Probably a very dangerous and time-consuming way to spend your zero-mile day. Maybe just for the paddles.
3. Wet-suits (or even dry-suits). Seal your gear in a bag with a trapped air-bubble for buoyancy.

**A multi-use strategy**

Ideally, the equipment used for crossing water is not dead-weight for the *terra-firma* majority of your trip. A wetsuit could double as an extra layer in very cold weather. A deflated inflatable kayak may also be used as a water-proof barrier for camping in wet areas.

What is the general aquatic strategy for a mostly land-based trek?

Comment: The discoverytrail.org site says "once you cross the bridge". Apparently there is an annual(?) run that crosses the bridge... if you timed it right. Sites say use uber or arrange a friend to take you across.

Comment: In this specific case I would probably be generous with ethics and just call a taxi. Crossing without proper equipment is dangerous and having that equipment adds a lot of weight

Comment: In many cases rerouting to walk round is a the best option for a purist.  Here Google reckons it would add about 100 miles, but claims you can't cross the Susquehanna downstream of Columbia, PA on foot even though PA-372 near Holtwood looks like it might be walkable.  On a bike, to get an indication of the shortest unpowered route, you're still adding 60-70 miles

Comment: Swimming 6km is even difficult in warm water and without any gear...

Comment: I just want to make very clear that if you wear a dry suit you should not have any intentionally trapped air for buoyancy. That is for dry bags ONLY. It is extremely dangerous and risks drowning to not properly burp a drysuit. Air can cause inversion holding you upside down under water, even with a PFD on.

Comment: Consider in 5C water survival time is around 90minutes with exhaustion in around 30minutes. At the mid you are 3km from shore, so around an hour swimming (for a strong competent swimmer) - i.e. no way you could make it if you fell out the boat.   Survival in that water temperature requires dry suit with fleece, attempting that crossing in a flimsy boat you could carry (e.g. packraft) is extremely dangerous.

Comment: @mattnz: Definitely learn a wet entry. With cold water practice. And inspect the raft. And check the currents/tides. And have an emergency phone to call for rescue. With a bright orange life jacket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than normal inflatable canoe or other boat, there's a specific thing called a "pack raft" that's specially designed for this sort of crossing.

They're built without much of the attempt at rigidity that normal inflatables have, but rather with a focus on being light enough to carry in a pack until required.

Comment: They can go below 5 lbs and keep you out of the water so definitely a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Out of those options inflatable boat is your best bet. Makeshifting something is pretty risky and relies a lot on your building skills, while 6km in a drysuit with gear(in a cold water) is straight up a bad idea.

Comment: Small update to my initial post:  we've got an Outcast Fat cat from a local outdoor stores  https://gritroutdoors.com/ last season and it's an absolutely phenomenal 1 man boat(plus fits nicely in our JL. Would definitely recommend